# flutter ImageIcon change size

Tags: flutter, icons, size

I have this `ImageIcon`:

```
            Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/images/group.png"), size: 50,))
```

I get this:
[image]

How can I make the icon take all the space available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FittedBox for stretch icon.

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            child: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/camera.png"))),)
```